# Autoloading the url and getting content on that page

Tags: javascript, php

I am ussing one API. Which give some live data when it is hit on browser.

like test this:

[api.frrole.com/v1/trending-topics?location=india&category=sports&timeinterval=1&apikey=Huqi12s8u9f5zp9NF7zF52b5ec082b523](http://api.frrole.com/v1/trending-topics?location=india&category=sports&timeinterval=1&apikey=7cOZtHXb0n789q8wss2w52aca8a1860fd)

when you click this link it will show some json string on the page.
Right now to get the result we have to manually enter link. I want something like this:

1. Above url should be hit automatically on the browser every 1 hour
2. The json result comes as result; I should capture that result in backend

For any given url, I can get the content on that page using `file_get_content()`. Once I get data on the page, I process it in my way. But it does not work for above link.

Is it possible to implement `1, 2 points`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$feedUrl = "http://api.frrole.com/v1/trending-topics?   location=india&category=sports&timeinterval=1&apikey=7cOZtHXb0n789q8wss2w52aca8a1860fd";
//Create a DOM object
$json = file_get_contents($feedUrl);

$code = json_decode($json);
var_dump($code);
```

After that you can put it in a function to be triggered once every hour